# Admin access to Wordpress site with installing plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Third party Wordpress dashboard tools like ManageWP or InfiniteWP have access to entire Wordpress site by installing theirs plugin on that site. This way they have admin access to my Wordpress site so they can update plugins, do site backup etc. **How this is possible and is it safe?**

I know that I can access Wordpress with XML-RPC but then I will need to supply administrator credentials.

Comment: it is impossible to know if it is safe or not without having access to their code and how their servers are managed. It is much better to just ask them for details instead of asking people to guess it.

Comment: @MarkKaplun at least for InfiniteWP, you can self host, and their code is open.

Comment: @janh so they are just irresponsible enough to suggest you host a control panel over http ;).... and once a hacker takes control of your panel he has control of all your sites. Now you are left with no help with finding a way out of this mess.

Comment: Exactly! That's why securing the management panel is the user's job, and it's the most important job when using it in my opinion. Thankfully, their system only reaches out, it does not require managed sites to be able to contact the management system, so it does not need to be publicly accessible and access to it can be limited by any kind of ACL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe if a) the management interface is only accessible by trusted users and b) there are no bugs. You can take care of a), but you'll have to trust them for b).

How it's done: they send you to a special URL on your live site and pass a signature by which the plugin on the site can tell that this request has been triggered by the management interface, then set the same session cookies WP would set if you logged in regularly, and finally they'll simply redirect you to the admin dashboard.

Comment: have you heard about the twitter guy that disabled trump's account? In the same way, it is safe only if you trust that no one of their employees will have an urge to delete your site.

Comment: True, but that's an inherent issue. Everybody who has access to the global management panel also has access to wp-admin, and therefore can mess up your site that way. You have to trust those you give the master key at least so much that you're fine with giving them a simple key. If you want to/should trust people with master keys is another issue entirely.

Comment: yes, which is why all security related questions are about trade off, how the ease you gain by using such services mitigate the risk that they have bad employee hiring process or just general bad security habits in securing their network. Without knowing what the OP's site do it is hard to have a black/white answer if it is safe or not

Comment: @janh Thanks for your answer. I don't understand part: "then set the same session cookies WP would set if you logged in regularly". How WordPress plugin can access session cookies of any user especially admin user?

Comment: When you log in normally, WP sets a few cookies by which it can later tell that you are logged in and auhenticated, e.g. `wordpress_$COOKIEHASH=...`, `wordpress_logged_in_$COOKIEHASH=....`, where $COOKIEHASH is either set in your config or md5($siteurl). InfiniteWP will set the same cookies, so for WP there is no difference whether you logged in with your username & password or via InfiniteWP.

Comment: @janh That makes sense now. Because plugin is part of same site it can access those cookies. But just one more question. How can plugin getAllCategories and result pass to InfiniteWP Management interface? I don't understand how Management interface request something from plugin how they communicate? Plugin then expose some methods as REST API or?

Comment: Exactly. In InfiniteWP's case, they don't use the REST API, but implement their own procedure. They'll make POST requests to the site in question and their plugin handles it. You'll see them in your log, looking like `POST /?no_cache_Q6Ub4R2S=1509716436` with a UserAgent string that contains InfiniteWP at the end and base64-encoded JSON data as content.

Comment: @janh Thanks. But if plugin can access cookies of administrative user I must first login to Wordpress to create authentication cookie. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: You must log in and install & enable the plugin as an admin user once(!). When it's active, it can do pretty much anything, including setting cookies for a user.

Comment: In that case it might be possible to create a separate admin user to do the install with and then filter that user's capabilities to restrict what actions it could perform as an admin. But it would take a familiarity with knowing exactly what permissions are required to perform the desired actions you *do* want to allow.